# How to say that $\epsilon$ should be small enough in a mathematical statement?

Tags: terminology, definition

Assuming I approximate $x$ by $y$ throughout minimizing $\|x-y\|_2^2$, I want to define $x$ as the approximate of $y$ when $\|x-y\|_2^2< \epsilon$ in a mathematical definition statement. Then, should I say

"We define $x$ as the approximate of $y$ when $\epsilon$ is *sufficiently*/*arbitrarily*/*properly* small"?

I mean what is the proper mathematical term in such cases to prevent any miss-interpretation and to send a clear message?

Comment: What's wrong with "take $x$ such that $||x - y||_2^2 < \epsilon$" ?

Comment: @Joe: Then shouldn't I say anything about $\epsilon$? Whether it is big or small or etc.?

Comment: If you simply say "Let $ \epsilon > 0$ " , then what you show will work for any $\epsilon$, big or small. However, if there's something else going on in the proof and you need $\epsilon$ to be sufficiently small for [property], just say so: "Let $\epsilon >0$ sufficiently small that [property]"

Comment: @Joe: Personally, I take this as an answer.

Comment: You could also talk about $x$ being an **$\varepsilon-$approximation** of $y$ when $||x-y||_2^2<\varepsilon$. Thus the approximation fitness depends on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: $\|x-y\|_2^2< \epsilon$ why is there a subscript 2, what does that notation mean.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

> For any vector $y\in \mathcal H$ and $\epsilon >0$, the vector $x\in \mathcal H$ is an $\epsilon$-approximation of $y$ if
>   $$ \| x - y\|_2^2 < \epsilon.$$